# In background check the Play Store to determine if an app is available to download on the device

Tags: android, google-play

I know I can link to the Play Store with the URL:

```
market://details?id=com.example.appname
```

What I would love to do is 'ping' this URL in the background, and determine if the app is actually available, then, I can modify my UI as appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume that, if app is unavailable, the page under [`http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>`](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%3Cpackage_name%3E) contains, for example, word `error-section`. If app is available, it does not contain this word.

Make HTTP GET to that URL and search for `error-section`.

- No `error-section` - your app is available.
- Otherwise, it's unavailable.

Like this:

```
final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
final String getURL = "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>";
final HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
final HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
final HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
if (resEntityGet != null) 
{  
    final String response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
    if (response.indexOf("error-section") == -1)
    {
        // available
    }
    else
    {
        // unavailable
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks reasonable.  Thanks for this.

Comment: This was a good idea, but didn't work.  I think the Web doesn't always filter based on device (so all checks come back valid - since the Web Page was there in the Play Store).

Answer (score 2):

```
private class URLTest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String strurl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars.ads.iap";
                // String strurl =
                // "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars.ads.iaptest";
                // //fake packagename append with "test"
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(strurl);
                HttpResponse httpresp = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                if (httpresp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    Log.e("Found", "YES");
                } else if (httpresp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND) {
                    Log.e("Found", "NO");
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("", "");
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

i tried with correct & fake packages and its giving bad request responze if the app not available & positive(success 200 code) if app is there..so plz check it once it might help u.

**android 2.2 & app min req 2.3**

[image: Correct URL 200 Response Success Result] [image: fake url. app url which is nt available on play store Failure result 404]

Comment: Well, your example will work, if the package doesn't exist, however, I am wanting to test with valid package names (not angrybirds_test).  I need to send a valid URL (containing a package), and have the Play Store respond.  Unfortunately, when I run this test for an app not on Android 2.3 (using my Nexus One) I still get a valid response back from the server (since the URL is valid - even though the app is not available on the server).

To be clear - using a fake package name is not a valid test - this needs to fail (because the app in not in the store), even if I supply a valid URL.

Comment: i have tested with available device and in question specify the api level in which u hve tested nd didnt work...so user can answer accordingly.it is giving response 200 if the app is available on market and if m passing package name which is not available on market thn it is giving response 404 Not Found...if poss thn gve url or package name for clarification.

Comment: I tested the previous code with a NexusOne running 2.3 (CyanogenMod).  I don't have that device with me, to check this nuance.  I hope it works, and will test it again (so I can award the bounty if applicable).

Comment: FYI classes which are used r not device dependent so thr wud b no chance to device compatibility issue HttpClient HttpGet  HttpResponse HttpStatus ,AsyncTask :) all are available from api 1.. :)...anyways check it from ur end..

Comment: It isn't the source files that are the problem, it is the Play Store Web site that is.  It is the response from the Play store which doesn't change based on device (and that is the point of my question).

Comment: What you are missing is the part about the Play store not returning an error code based on the device version.  The test in your code (with an invalid URL: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars.ads.iaptest) is not valid.  This needs to fail (only on devices that don't support Angry Birds, based on OS version (with a valid URL).  This is not a source code compatibility issue, but you are missing the original intention of my question.

Comment: ok so jst need to check tht if playstore app min api req version is more thn device os thn will work or not ?